# How can I perform a task in java android app when the app has no instance or is inactive

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks

I am beginner in java.
**I want to perform a task when the app has no instance or is inactive.**
Can anyone help me by **giving a simple code on how to do it** Please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Background Service`. You can follow this official tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/background